# Magento1 | Collection how get all products where qty > 1, build query

Tags: magento-1.9, collection

I have this code

```
       $productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
        ->getCollection()
        ->addAttributeToFilter('attribute_set_id',array(12,4))
        ->setPageSize(35000)
        ->load();
```

How to build a query like this, get all products WHERE QTY > 1
How i can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this

```
$productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
        ->getCollection()
        ->addAttributeToFilter('attribute_set_id',array(12,4))
        ->setPageSize(35000);

Mage::getSingleton('cataloginventory/stock')
    ->addInStockFilterToCollection($productCollection);
```